# Procedural generation

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm interested in generating procedural map using php, it can be static. I just need to get me on the right way... I red a lot of articles about it and understand that I need to use noise generation to get basic map shape. but what after that?! I will be using simple tiles 32x32. It it even  possible/efficient to do it via php?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are trying to achieve? Also why would you use web technologies for such a task? Thanks

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/T0o4T.png, something like this. it's going to be web based game.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using Perlin or OpenSimplex noise.

You can either implement this yourself or simply use a library:

https://github.com/martinlindhe/php-noisegenerator

You can generate a heightmap into an array using this library:

```
$perlin = new \NoiseGenerator\PerlinNoise(3000);
$width = 100;
$height = 100;

$octaves = array(64, 16, 4, 2);
$noise = array();
for ($y = 0; $y < $height; $y += 1) {
    for ($x = 0; $x < $width; $x += 1) {
        $num = $perlin->noise($x, $y, 0, $octaves);
        $raw = ($num / 2) + .5;
        if ($raw < 0) $raw = 0;
        $noise[$x][$y] = $raw;
    }
}
```

Now that you have your noise array populated, you can represent this with color on your front end using JS or whatever you want. I'll let you figure out the details on that end, but essentially, find the range of your numbers in your heightmap and determine thresholds for different types of terrain.

I wrote a tutorial on generating heightmaps and rendering them using noise over here: https://plaxdev.wordpress.com/2017/05/04/procedurally-generating-islands/

This doesn't use PHP, only JavaScript, but the idea behind rendering the heightmap in JS is included in that article if you're struggling with that.